# Where to fill session after authenticating via WSFederationAuthenticationModule

Tags: session, authentication, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, acs

We are using WSFederationAuthenticationModule in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application to authenticate users via Windows Azure ACS. We have tried multiple things to save some user specific data in the session after the authentication has succeeded but everytime we write to the session object we got the exception 'Session state is not available in this context'. Our favorite was the event System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SignedIn but of course at this time the session does not exist. Where is the recommended place to write initial data of an currently authenticated user into the session?

Comment: What sort of data are you looking to write?

Comment: We want to do a database lookup to load the user profile for example and save the profile data in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [ClaimsAuthenticationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthenticationmanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this?  The beauty of this is that you can access the current claims for the authenticated user (before your application code is executed), run whatever query you need to run, and then stuff new claims into the claimset of the principal.  I've used this technique before for similar situations as you described.

If you really need to get access to the session data, then I think you want to look at the [SessionSecurityTokenHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.sessionsecuritytokenhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Unfortunately the session is neither available at the time the ClaimsAuthenticationManager is called nor at the time the SessionSecurityTokenHandler is called also. Now i have used the trick picky bagging the data by request.Items and put them in the session in Application_AcquireRequestState.

Comment: The ClaimsAuthenticationManager was just a suggested alternative solution.  The SessionSecurityTokenHandler is absolutely where you can access the session or even take over creating it if you want.  Either way, glad to hear you have something that works for you.